# How to bring Database Online in my online site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I had make my database offline in Sql studio by Right clicking to my Database> Tasks>Take Offline. After it my login stops in SQL Studio. I had make another database user from which i login. But it shows my Database offline. When I used to Right click on my Database>Tasks>Bring Online. It says me you do'nt have a privilege to alter database.Any help will be great. I had also used the query to bring online but same result.

```
   ALTER DATABASE rein SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bring SQL Server database online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194702/bring-sql-server-database-online)

Comment: My question is not for local database

Comment: If it is the duplicate it will be solved on online server

Comment: That's what the problem is, you don't have direct access to the machine on which the db is to bring it back online. Which is what the answer in that question points out. Anyway, will revert my close vote to see if this is somehow a different problem.

Comment: Now what is the solution. I had also contacted bigrock for this

Comment: The solution is to get the people who administrate the server to either give you more rights (which can be doubtful depending on your situation) - or get them to bring it online for you.

Answer (score 0):

solution is to call administrate the server to either give you more privilege or themselves bring it online for you.