# No process is on the other end of the pipe exception when restoring database

Tags: c#, sql-server, restore

When I attempt to restore my backup database it restores the database successfully but when log out the system it gives me the exception"A transport-level error occured when sending the request to the server. (Provider:Shared memory provider, error 0-No process is on the other end of the pipe)" ... how this can be solved
My codes for restoring database are:

```
 private void restoreBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string database = cn.Database.ToString();
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                string sqlres1=string.Format("ALTER DATABASE ["+database+"] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
                SqlCommand command1=new SqlCommand(sqlres1,cn);
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string sqlres2 = "USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE ["+database+"] FROM DISK='"+restoretxt.Text+"' WITH REPLACE";
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sqlres2, cn);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string sqlres3 = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [" + database + "] SET MULTI_USER");
                SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(sqlres3, cn);
                command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Database restore done successfully");
                this.Close();
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This can happen if the DB is left offline when restoring. You set single user in your first statement, but I would speculate that the multiuser setting is not correctly working. Try setting `ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET ONLINE`. If it doesn't work initially, try using the SA account. This post may be helpful -= http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194702/bring-sql-server-database-online

Comment: When you execute `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` it will kill existing connections and they will see that error message. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am asking or want a explain about this error and why its happening specially I'm confused because the restore process done successfully but this exception occurs when I'm leaving my system ... If you can explain this to me and give me a solution please ... regards

Comment: @Alex I tried your code "ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET ONLINE" but same problem occur

Comment: @Tima'aTamim, the error essentially means that nothing is listening for your command. There are a lot of possible reasons for this, and many posts on SO discussing it. We will need more information to help, but for a start, how do you know the restore worked? Just because you have no SQL errors doesn't mean for certain it has worked. Also, why are you calling `this.Close();`?

Comment: @Alex I do know that the restore is done successfully because I made some changes in my database and then I had restore it and it is as same as it was when I created the backup ... this.Close() is for closing the form when the process done successfully

Comment: @Tima'aTamim, ok as a test here, remove the `USE MASTER`. If you are logged in with the correct user permissions to do the restore, you should not need to switch to MASTER. What state is your connection in when you call the method? If you're opening it, I presume it's created elsewhere. If you are connected as a normal user, you will need to reconnect with a privileged user to make changes. If you already have permissions, USE MASTER shouldn't be necessary. Also, do you see the messagebox telling you the restore completed?

Comment: @Alex when I remove "USE MASTER" an exception occurs talling that "A use of master database is recommended" and yes I see the messagebox telling you the restore completed when using my above codes